# Why pages aren't indexed in Google Search Console

Tags: seo, google-search-console

I created a blog page using nextjs and registered a Google Search Console page. Just in case, I also registered a sitemap and found 14 pages.

However, the total number of indexed pages is 6. Why are my pages not indexed even though I have requested them to be indexed through URL verification?

And do I have to inconveniently request the page to be indexed on Google every time? If I change the META HEAD tag of a blog post page, do I have to request indexing of all blog post pages again?